# NancyFX Catch All route

Tags: url-routing, single-page-application, nancy

Does NancyFX supports ASP.NET MVC like 'Catch All' route? I need one, that basically match every URL. This is very handy for building up Single Page applications.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using Regex

```
Get[@"/(.*)"] = parameters => {
    return View["viewname", parameters];
};
```

But you don't really need it for building a Single Page Application with NancyFX - you can just use Get and Post with all your routing logic and still have a single page app.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Why I need it, cause I have Backbone-powered SPA with push state enabled. Then I routed to say localhost:8080/some/1 page inside SPA - it's all works fine. But I can copy URL and send it to friend, as he try to open he will get 404. So, I need to catch all routes and handle master.html view, the reset is build by JS.

Comment: You can see the details in code [here](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/candidate)

Comment: You also can use **Greedy Segments** https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern

Answer (score 17):

`Tested in Nancy version 0.23.2`

`Get[@"/(.*)"]` did not work for me as a catch-all route.  The routes **"/"**, **"/foo/bar"**, and longer routes would not catch.  It seems like there's no getting around having to define a `Get["/"]` route for the root URL.  Nothing else seems to catch it (tried `Get["{uri*}"]`).  Here's how I ended up defining my routes (keep in mind I'm doing this for an Angular application):

```
Get["/views/{uri*}"] = _ => { return "A partial view..."; };
Get["/"] =
Get["/{uri*}"] = _ =>
{
    var uri = (string)_.uri;// The captured route
    // If you're using OWIN, you can also get a reference to the captured route with:
    var environment = this.Context.GetOwinEnvironment();// GetOwinEnvironment is in the 'Nancy.Owin' namespace
    var requestPath = (string)environment["owin.RequestPath"];
    return View["views/defaultLayout.html"];
};
```

It's important to understand [Pattern Scoring](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern-scoring).  The route patterns are weighted, if two routes match the same url segment, the higher score wins.  The catch-all pattern is weighted `0` and even though the `/views/{uri*}` route pattern is also a catch-all, it starts with a literal, which is weighted `10000`, so it will win out on all routes that start with */views*.

Here's more info on [Accessing Owin's Environment Variables](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin#accessing-owin-environment-variables).  Note that the captured `uri` variable and `requestPath` will be slightly different.  The `requestPath` will start with a `/` where as the `uri` variable will not.  Also, if the matched route pattern is `Get["/"]`, `uri` will be `null` and `requestPath` will be `"/"`.

The *Views* route will return a partial html file, based on the url path, and all other routes will return the default Layout page that will bootstrap the SPA.

Answer (score 8):

An updated answer for whom @synhershko 's solution does not work. Try:

```
Get[@"^(.*)$"] = parameters => {
    return "hi";
};
```

This will capture all paths except for the index page. I am not sure if this will work in the context of Angular, but this worked for me when trying to hack together a simple server with just one handler.

Comment: This should be the answer for NancyFx > 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Answer provided by @synhershko does not work for me. It does not handle /users/2 or any other route containing more segements.

Below code works on my machine ;) :

```
public class IndexModule : NancyModule
{
    dynamic IndexPage() { return View["Index"]; }

    public IndexModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => { return IndexPage(); };
        Get["/(.*)"] = _ => { return IndexPage(); };
        Get["/(.*)/(.*)"] = _ => { return IndexPage(); };
        Get["/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)"] = _ => { return IndexPage(); };
    }
}
```

My solution is not perfect, cause it does not match *everything*. I repeated as many '/(.*)' as in my longest Angular route.

Comment: The IndexPage method should return `Negotiator` which is what `View[...]` returns.  I would also pass in the parameters variable to have access to that: `public Negotiator GetIndexPage(dynamic _) {...};` Then you can just reference that on all your methods: `Get["/"] = IndexPage;` etc... Or just have them fall through instead of defining the `IndexPage` method: `Get["/"] = Get["/(.*)"] = ... = _ => { ... };` But I would avoid the multi-catch-alls altogether and use `Get["/"] = Get["/{uri*}"] = _ => { ... };` See my answer for more details.