# NancyFX and Single Page Application

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

I'm using AngularJS with html5 mode (push state), which means i have to send my main view (index.html) for all routes except /api/. 
Solution from [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679553/nancyfx-catch-all-route) does not work. It only matches routes after one slash ex. '*/register*', '*/login*', etc. It does not match '*/*', '*user/RlyDontKnow/Profile*' and all this kind of routes with two or more '*/*'.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Try to explain your problem in more detail, preferably with some code attached.

Comment: I want to render the the same main view for all routes, because routing is handled by AngularJS with Html5Mode on. Does not matter if it's "/" or "/user/register". So far i found this method: 
Get["/(.*)"] = x => View["main"];

but it does not work. The question is: How to response with same view for any route.

Comment: Why would you put many routes? Can't you just have / ?

Comment: I could if i would not use push state. With just '/' if user goes directly to '/register' or refresh the page, you need to send your main view/index.html again.

Comment: I have the same issue and I solved it like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24707794/883793